# SecurityException: Caller no longer running

Tags: android, android-asynctask, job-scheduling, jobintentservice

I am facing below issue in **Android** O and above when trying to run my **JobIntentService**, I am having a tough time to reproduce the issue :

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Caller no longer running, last stopped +206ms because: timed out while starting
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
   at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.dequeueWork(IJobCallback.java:191)
   at android.app.job.JobParameters.dequeueWork(JobParameters.java:196)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl.dequeueWork(JobIntentService.java:314)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService.dequeueWork(JobIntentService.java:639)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:389)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:382)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: crash happened when JobIntentService.enque() service

Comment: Check [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293), and consider updating your question with your `JobService` implementation.

Comment: See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293 Looks like it's an issue Google isn't helping with.

Comment: @Santhosh any solutions?

Comment: @Santhosh did u find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Let your jobIntentService extend MyJobIntentService

This will handle multiple dequeueWork call going to remoteProcess,
even if the remoteProcess throws a security exception for popping already removed work off the stack

```
package android.support.v4.app;

import timber.log.Timber;

public abstract class MyJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {   
 
    @Override

    GenericWorkItem dequeueWork() { 
        try {
            return super.dequeueWork();
        } catch (SecurityException ignored) {
            Timber.e(ignored);
        }    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: Important to create a package "android.support.v4.app"
Since the GenericWorkItem class is inside this package to gain access.

Comment: `GenericWorkItem` is a protected class. I can't access it whille extending the JobIntentService.

Comment: Same issue. This is not a complete answer.

Comment: i assume that you have not created a package name
try creating a package ---android.support.v4.app---
then add the file inside that... you will be able to access GenericWorkItem.

Comment: Yeah I see now that you are saying to create a package that matches the support libraries path in your app, allowing you to access these functions. Though that means you have to test this code every time you version bump the support library. Not really a solution I would do unless I had absolutely no choice.

Comment: according to comments on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293), e.g. #120 & #121, that may cause another problem - `onHandleWork` not getting called...